# Vaadin flow - Having views in a different package

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

Exists in vaadin flow an option to have the views in a different package and not as a subpackage where the main spring boot class is located? e.g.

```
com.xyz.vaadin.app --> Spring Boot Main
com.xyz.vaadin.config
com.xyz.vaadin.views  --> Main view
```

I already tried to use "@SpringBootApplication scanBasePackages" or "scanBasePackageClasses" and passed the main view package or main view class but after starting the application it does not found the view. Error "Route is not found"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the `@EnableVaadin` annotation on your Spring application class, and supply the package name. So in your example it would be

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableVaadin(value = "com.xyz.vaadin.views")
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainClass.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be triggered when you instantiate "RouterLink" with views/component that aren't annotated with "@Route". It happens even if you actually don't try to access to this particular view.